# Message sent by server are not receiving on the client side

Tags: java, websocket

The message coming from one client is coming to the Java server. When a server sends this message to the another client, server showing "message sent" but that message is not received by the client in ws.onmessage block.

```js
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/sampleWebsocket//serverendpointdemo/client1");
ws.onmessage = function(event) {
  alert("msg");
  var str = event.data;
}
```

Comment: Seem like a server side problem. Show us that code.

Comment: hello @gre_gor , Actually my is a little bit different. The server code is working properly on localhost. But I deployed to the cloud server , I am getting the message from the first client to the server. It is showing sent message but that not receiving to the onmessage block of second client

Comment: Sorry for your inconvenience

Comment: If it's deployed to the cloud server, why are you connecting to `localhost`?

Comment: that is the local server address I have added here.

Comment: But the problem is if the server is showing message sent then why it is not receiving at the client ?

Comment: Which server? Local or cloud?

Comment: Cloud server . The project on the local server is working properly. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for response to my question. The actual problem was because of my Redhat cloud. Cloud server was very slow that is why this problem came. When I tried to restart my server, that data was coming properly on my ws.onmessage block.